# Rails distance_of_time_in_words returns "en, about_x_hours"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, time, actionview

I'm having a weird problem, hoping someone knows what the issue is...

Using distance_of_time_in_words (and consequently time_ago_in_words) is not returning the actual time distance. Instead it is returning things like "en, about_x_hours" or "en, x_minutes".

The pattern is correct, as in:

```
time_ago_in_words(50.minutes.ago) => "en, about_x_hours"
time_ago_in_words(3.minutes.ago) => "en, x_minutes"
```

But why on earth is it displaying "x" instead of the actual number, "_" instead of spaces, and "en, " at the beginning of all of that?!

Comment: strange... i tried on both Rails 3.0.1 and 2.2.2 and they both gave "about 1 hour".

Comment: definitely strange... i'm running 2.3.8 btw... if it makes a difference. my uneducated guess would be that it has something to do with internationalization? i'm guessing "en" indicates it should be in english? dunno... wild guess.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

So I finally got it to work!! Hope this helps anyone who might have the same problem...

Basically half of what Lichtamberg first said was correct. The en.yml had to be as follows:

```
en:
  x_minutes:
    one:   "1 minute"
    other: "%{count} minutes"
```

Note that `x_minutes` is not under `datetime` and that it has `one` and `other`. Further, there is no need for `I18n.l` as I18n is already implemented in the `distance_of_time_in_words` method.

So with the above (plus all the other about_x_hours, x_days, etc patterns that you can find on the file Lichtamberg included), just do:

```
time_ago_in_words(3.minutes.ago)
```

And... voila!

Comment: from rails console, use `helper.time_ago_in_words(3.minutes.ago)`

Answer (score 11):

That gives back a string to translate via the I18n-gem.... Try following:

```
# I18n.localize(string)
I18n.l time_ago_in_words(3.minutes.ago)
```

And add (if doesnt exist) following in

```
# config/locales/en.yml
en:
  datetime:
    distance_in_words:
      ...
      less_than_x_minutes:
        one: "less than a minute"
        other: "less than %{count} minutes"
      x_minutes:
        one: "1 minute"
        other: "%{count} minutes"
      about_x_hours:
        one: "about 1 hour"
        other: "about %{count} hours"
      ....
```

And be sure to include following (maybe customized) data in your en.yml:

http://github.com/svenfuchs/rails-i18n/blob/master/rails/locale/en.yml

Please tell me if it works..

Comment: The above gives me the following error: Object must be a Date, DateTime or Time object. "about x minutes" given.

Comment: hmmmmm i tried the updated code but i still get: Object must be a Date, DateTime or Time object. "<span class=\"translation_missing\">en, x_minutes</span>" given. :(

Comment: so i finally figured it out. thanks for your help! i couldn't have done it without you! though i'm still confused as to why it didn't just work... no one else seemed to have a problem...

Answer (score 0):

Shamelessly ripped off [time_ago_in_words => "in {{count}} days."?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4330403/time-ago-in-words-in-count-days/4385186#4385186)

Rails was using some deprecated syntax in the helper which then got dropped in the latest Ruby version. If you are using something like Heroku, try telling your production instance to use Rails 2.3.9. Otherwise you can also try downgrading Ruby.

See the changelog: http://weblog.rubyonrails.org/2010/9/4/ruby-on-rails-2-3-9-released

```
Changes i18n named-interpolation syntax from the deprecated Hello {{name}} to the 1.9-native Hello %{name}.
```