# Rails 3.2 Time ago in words Method returns html content

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.1, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I wanted to display datetime in words, like "1 hour ago" and i tried the following method but it is returning returning html in the string format as shown below.

## method

```
helper.time_ago_in_words(Time.now)
```

## result

```
=> "<span class=\"translation_missing\" title=\"translation missing: en.less_than_x_minutes\">Less Than X Minutes</span>"
```

rails console output:

```
>> helper.time_ago_in_words(Time.now)
=> "<span class=\"translation_missing\" title=\"translation missing: en.less_than_x_minutes\">Less Than X Minutes</span>"
>> I18n.locale = :de
=> :de
>> helper.time_ago_in_words(Time.now)
=> "<span class=\"translation_missing\" title=\"translation missing: de.less_than_x_minutes\">Less Than X Minutes</span>"
>> I18n.locale = :en
=> :en
>> helper.time_ago_in_words(Time.now)
=> "<span class=\"translation_missing\" title=\"translation missing: en.less_than_x_minutes\">Less Than X Minutes</span>"
```

Comment: Your right the docs act like it should return a string... http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/DateHelper.html#method-i-time_ago_in_words. I don't know a solution but thanks for asking this so I, and others, can keep an eye out for this later.

Answer (score 1):

Do you use any locales in config? English is for sure the default one and it should work correctly.

```
2.0.0p0 :001 > helper.time_ago_in_words(Time.now)
 => "less than a minute" 
2.0.0p0 :002 > I18n.locale = :de
 => :de 
2.0.0p0 :003 > helper.time_ago_in_words(Time.now)
 => "translation missing: de.datetime.distance_in_words.less_than_x_minutes" 
2.0.0p0 :004 > I18n.locale = :en
 => :en 
2.0.0p0 :005 > helper.time_ago_in_words(Time.now)
 => "less than a minute"
```

Could you try to invoke this method on helper object, like I did in console (rails c)? What is the output?

Comment: thanks for the reply, i have updated the output in the above question please check.

Comment: What Rails version do you use? If nothing will work, then the only option for you is to define those translations explicitly, like [here - link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4007073/rails-distance-of-time-in-words-returns-en-about-x-hours). You can find file with default translations [here - link](https://github.com/svenfuchs/rails-i18n/blob/master/rails/locale/en.yml).

Answer (score 0):

In a rails console, if I just use time_ago_in_words from ActionView::Helpers, I'll get the translation_missing error message. But if I include from ActionView::Helpers::DateHelper, it'll work as expected.

works:

```
[2] pry(main)> include ActionView::Helpers::DateHelper
=> Object 
[3] pry(main)> time_ago_in_words(Time.now)
=> "less than a minute"
```

translation missing:

```
[1] pry(main)> include ActionView::Helpers
=> Object [2] 
pry(main)> time_ago_in_words(Time.now)
=> "<span class=\"translation_missing\" title=\"translation missing: en.less_than_x_minutes\">Less Than X Minutes</span>"
```

Comment: I get the same result either way — the string with HTML (Rails 4).

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

> time_ago_in_words(Time.now)