# Rails - duration of time in days, months and years

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, datetime

Is there a Rails helper or other Ruby method for taking a DateTime object and translating into something like?

- "13 days" (if under a month)
- "3 months" (if under a year)
- "1 year, 3 months"

I'm familiar with Rails [built-in helpers](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/DateHelper.html#method-i-distance_of_time_in_words), but looking for something that will give me the output above.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Rails helper method is what you want, then you customize it using i18n.
Check out these answers: [Rails distance_of_time_in_words returns "en, about_x_hours"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4007073/rails-distance-of-time-in-words-returns-en-about-x-hours)

Also, look how this is implemented:
https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/actionpack/lib/action_view/helpers/date_helper.rb

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps [distance_of_time_in_words](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/DateHelper.html#method-i-distance_of_time_in_words) is what you're looking for:

```
distance_of_time_in_words(from_time, from_time + 50.minutes)        # => about 1 hour
distance_of_time_in_words(from_time, 50.minutes.from_now)           # => about 1 hour
distance_of_time_in_words(from_time, from_time + 15.seconds)        # => less than a minute
distance_of_time_in_words(from_time, from_time + 15.seconds, true)  # => less than 20 seconds
distance_of_time_in_words(from_time, 3.years.from_now)              # => about 3 years
distance_of_time_in_words(from_time, from_time + 60.hours)          # => 3 days
distance_of_time_in_words(from_time, from_time + 45.seconds, true)  # => less than a minute
distance_of_time_in_words(from_time, from_time - 45.seconds, true)  # => less than a minute
distance_of_time_in_words(from_time, 76.seconds.from_now)           # => 1 minute
distance_of_time_in_words(from_time, from_time + 1.year + 3.days)   # => about 1 year
distance_of_time_in_words(from_time, from_time + 3.years + 6.months) # => over 3 years
distance_of_time_in_words(from_time, from_time + 4.years + 9.days + 30.minutes + 5.seconds) # => about 4 years
```

Comment: The guy put a link for this exact function in his description - he is not looking for it.